# Setting up netbox, AttributeError: module 'secrets' has no attribute 'choice'

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

I'm trying to set up Netbox on a RedHat 8 server and have hit a roadblock when trying to run the script to create the netbox superuser: python3 manage.py createsuperuser. I'm prompted for a new username/email/password, however afterward I get the error:
 AttributeError: module 'secrets' has no attribute 'choice'
I'm running python 3.6, and the script does have import secrets already. Anyone know why choice wouldn't be recognized? I tried looking through previous threads but didn't find anything related to the secrets module.

edit: here is the script-

```
"""
Django's standard crypto functions and utilities.
"""
import hashlib
import hmac
import secrets

from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes


def salted_hmac(key_salt, value, secret=None):
    """
    Return the HMAC-SHA1 of 'value', using a key generated from key_salt and a
    secret (which defaults to settings.SECRET_KEY).

    A different key_salt should be passed in for every application of HMAC.
    """
    if secret is None:
        secret = settings.SECRET_KEY

    key_salt = force_bytes(key_salt)
    secret = force_bytes(secret)

    # We need to generate a derived key from our base key.  We can do this by
    # passing the key_salt and our base key through a pseudo-random function and
    # SHA1 works nicely.
    key = hashlib.sha1(key_salt + secret).digest()

    # If len(key_salt + secret) > sha_constructor().block_size, the above
    # line is redundant and could be replaced by key = key_salt + secret, since
    # the hmac module does the same thing for keys longer than the block size.
    # However, we need to ensure that we *always* do this.
    return hmac.new(key, msg=force_bytes(value), digestmod=hashlib.sha1)


def get_random_string(length=12,
                      allowed_chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'):
    """
    Return a securely generated random string.

    The default length of 12 with the a-z, A-Z, 0-9 character set returns
    a 71-bit value. log_2((26+26+10)^12) =~ 71 bits
    """
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(allowed_chars) for i in range(length))


def constant_time_compare(val1, val2):
    """Return True if the two strings are equal, False otherwise."""
    return secrets.compare_digest(force_bytes(val1), force_bytes(val2))


def pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, dklen=0, digest=None):
    """Return the hash of password using pbkdf2."""
    if digest is None:
        digest = hashlib.sha256
    dklen = dklen or None
    password = force_bytes(password)
    salt = force_bytes(salt)
    return hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(digest().name, password, salt, iterations, dklen)
```

Comment: You need to show the code, at least the part that call `secrets.choice(...`

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue after moving my project to production. I had named a "secrets.py" file for use with db and secret_key settings (to easily ignore from git) and apparently that name conflicted and broke my admin view.

Simply changing the name of my secrets.py file resolved my issue.